# WordPress - Same page slug but different overall URL using custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

So I have a custom post type for some "Translations" that a client wants to add, they do not want to translate the entire website this rules out using "Poly Lang" etc to do this for me.

I have the custom post type and a custom taxonomy declared like so:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function prefix_translated_cpt()
{
    $labels = [
        'name' => _x('Translated Content', 'Post Type General Name', 'theme-slug'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Translated Content', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'theme-slug'),
        'menu_name' => __('Translations', 'theme-slug'),
        'name_admin_bar' => __('Translations', 'theme-slug'),
        'archives' => __('Translation Archives', 'theme-slug'),
        'attributes' => __('Translation Attributes', 'theme-slug'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Item:', 'theme-slug'),
        'all_items' => __('All Items', 'theme-slug'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'theme-slug'),
        'new_item' => __('New Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'view_item' => __('View Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'view_items' => __('View Items', 'theme-slug'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'not_found' => __('Not found', 'theme-slug'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Not found in Trash', 'theme-slug'),
        'featured_image' => __('Featured Image', 'theme-slug'),
        'set_featured_image' => __('Set featured image', 'theme-slug'),
        'remove_featured_image' => __('Remove featured image', 'theme-slug'),
        'use_featured_image' => __('Use as featured image', 'theme-slug'),
        'insert_into_item' => __('Insert into item', 'theme-slug'),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __('Uploaded to this item', 'theme-slug'),
        'items_list' => __('Items list', 'theme-slug'),
        'items_list_navigation' => __('Items list navigation', 'theme-slug'),
        'filter_items_list' => __('Filter items list', 'theme-slug'),
    ];
    $args = [
        'label' => __('Translated Content', 'theme-slug'),
        'description' => __('Translated custom post type.', 'theme-slug'),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => [
            'title',
            'editor',
            'revisions',
            'page-attributes'
        ],
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => '/language/%prefix_translated_lang_code%',
            'with_front' => false
        ],
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
    ];

    register_post_type('prefix_translation', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'prefix_translated_cpt');

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function prefix_translated_lang_code()
{

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Language Codes', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'theme-slug'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Language Code', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'theme-slug'),
        'menu_name' => __('Language Code', 'theme-slug'),
        'all_items' => __('All Items', 'theme-slug'),
        'parent_item' => __('Parent Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Item:', 'theme-slug'),
        'new_item_name' => __('New Item Name', 'theme-slug'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'view_item' => __('View Item', 'theme-slug'),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate items with commas', 'theme-slug'),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add or remove items', 'theme-slug'),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from the most used', 'theme-slug'),
        'popular_items' => __('Popular Items', 'theme-slug'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Items', 'theme-slug'),
        'not_found' => __('Not Found', 'theme-slug'),
        'no_terms' => __('No items', 'theme-slug'),
        'items_list' => __('Items list', 'theme-slug'),
        'items_list_navigation' => __('Items list navigation', 'theme-slug'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => false,
    );

    register_taxonomy('prefix_translated_lang_code', ['prefix_translation'], $args);
    $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->use_verbose_page_rules = true;
}

add_action('init', 'prefix_translated_lang_code');

function translation_post_link($url, $post)
{

    if (is_object($post) && 'prefix_translation' == $post->post_type) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'prefix_translated_lang_code');
        if ($terms) {
            $url = str_replace('%prefix_translated_lang_code%', $terms[0]->slug, $url);
        }
    }

    return $url;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'translation_post_link', 10, 2);
```

So this is working fine in terms of I can now make posts with URL's for example like so.

`domain.com/languages/en/page-slug`

However I can't make a new page like so:

`domain.com/languages/fr/page-slug`

It will end up as `page-slug-2` because WordPress will auto convert this when you try and use the same slug.

This post type also supports using child pages like

`domain.com/languages/en/page-slug/child-page`

So first I am trying to find a solution that could be used for page-slug but it would need to also support child page structure.

Can anyone point me to something that might help me solve this issue? or if its impossible? I am curious to know how Polylang manages to achieve using URL structures with the same name I think it only "appears" as the same name but it must be different in the back ground if its possible to do this method where as long as the URL looks correct on the frontend it doesn't necessarily have to correct in the default slug box of the page edit screen.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://polylang.pro/doc/can-posts-or-terms-share-the-same-url-slug-across-translations/#:~:text=With%20Polylang%20Pro%20comes%20the,3%E2%80%9D%20to%20the%20third%20etc.

Comment: This is very unhelpful thanks @MartinMirchev like I said in my actual question in the first sentence, Polylang is NO USE in this situation because when you use it forces all posts / pages to become translatable, as I said I do not want to use this on the base posts and pages only the custom post type.

Comment: I'm facing same situation, did you get chance to resolve this?

Comment: @BuyaKublai Not really I ended up having to just use different page slugs in the end as there was nothing simple I could find to get around this.